# dll for face recognition

Tags: android, .net, face-recognition

I started creating a face recognition application. But nothing works fine. Is any dll available for this so that I can decode the source and implement it ? Any reference or source will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). And this [list](http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-50-face-detection-recognition-apis) may help you.

Comment: OpenCV I tried already. Let me see the second one.